# How to save all occurences of a substring to an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, substring, between

I want to save each value between "(" and ")" from the string "obs1" to an array.

```
obs1 = "3341 - SSS - ELO CRED - (48,00)

4526 - SSS

7837 - SSS - MASTER DEB - (25,00)

2830 - SSS - VISA CRED - (35,00)"
```

I use the function

```
def find_between( s, first, last ):
    try:
            start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
            end = s.index( last, start )
            return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""
```

then print

```
print(find_between(obs1, "(", ")"))
```

which outputs

```
48,00
```

However, what I want to do is save the numbers

```
48,00
25,00
35,00
```

to an array, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.findall`:

```py
import re

obs1 = """3341 - SSS - ELO CRED - (48,00)

4526 - SSS

7837 - SSS - MASTER DEB - (25,00)

2830 - SSS - VISA CRED - (35,00)"""

output = re.findall(r"\((.*?)\)", obs1)
print(output) # ['48,00', '25,00', '35,00']
```

Comment: Note to OP: obviously it's very important to fully understand the regex you put in `re.findall`, because it may also catch cases you don't want (for example, if there's noting between '(' and ')').